# Multithreading address space

Tags: multithreading

Threads have their own call stack, then what kind of memory do different threads share. Do they have their own stack memory within the address space of a process? Is that memory sufficient for spawning 100s of threads? If a process has an object B, in case of Java it will be created on the heap. So, how are threads spawned by that process able to have access to that object on the heap ?

Comment: Some of your question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12389676/179850

Answer (score 0):

> kind of memory do different threads share

"All the process (user mode) memory" is available on all threads, this means that you can share objects stored a thread stack to other thread.

> Do they have their own stack memory within the address space of a
>   process
>   Yes each thread have its own stack for running.
>
> Is that memory sufficient for spawning 100s of threads?

Yes check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774(v=vs.85).aspx

> So, how are threads spawned by that process able to have access to
>   that object on the heap ?

I think that I answer that in the first question